C17 and the tmpnam function: A name that is "not the same as the name of an existing file."
I realize that tmpnam is considered dangerous and a safer alternative should be used, but my question is about what C17 7.21.4.4.2 has to say about tmpnam:

The tmpnam function generates a string that is a valid file name and that is not the same as the name of an existing file.  The function is potentially capable of generating at least TMP_MAX different strings, but any or all of them may already be in use by existing files and thus not be suitable return values.

What is the precise meaning of "an existing file" in the first sentence.  Does "an existing file" refer only to files the current process has open at the instant tmpnam is called, files only in the process's working directory at that instant, files anywhere in the operating system's file system at that instant, or something else entirely?

It means that it will be different than any other filename in the folder/directory where the temporary file would be created.

Ken White - Is that behavior mentioned somewhere in the language standard?

I don't know offhand. I just know how the function has worked since it was introduced.

"The tmpnam function generates a string that is a valid file name and that is not the same as the name of an existing file."
It's "an existing file" period. The standard doesn't limit it to files created (and not yet removed) by the current program. The returned string is a filename that does not exist in the filesystem.
Of course, if you try to actually create a file with that name, another program may have beaten you to it, but when tmpnam generated the string, there was no file with that name in the filesystem.

The C standard never defines the term "exist" as it refers to files.  But presumably, each implementation has some underlying notion of file existence  that C's notion maps to.
From within the C standard itself, all we know is that "existence" is some state that any given file may or may not have.  But we do know some facts about "existence".  For example, if a file with name n does not exist, then fopen(n, "r") shall fail, and if it does exist, then fopen(n, "x") shall fail.  So we could say that if fopen(tmpnam(NULL), "r") could be executed race-free in such a way that no other filesystem operations happened in between tmpnam and fopen (which, let us note, is not actually possible on typical modern operating systems), then the fopen call would fail.  Similarly, fopen(tmpnam(NULL), "x") would be expected to succeed unless some unrelated error occurred (no permission to create files, disk full, etc).
The C standard does not include the concept of "directory", since it's expected that it can be implemented on systems that do not support directories or any such mechanism.  So your question about "working directory" is unanswerable, or rather simply meaningless, from the point of view of the standard.
However, on systems which do support hierarchical directories, tmpnam() is normally implemented such that it returns a fully qualified pathname, e.g. /tmp/fileAABBCCDD, to a file that does not exist on the filesystem.  Thus (barring race conditions) you can open the filename returned by tmpnam() and get the same behavior no matter what your working directory is.

I think the relationship of the returned filename with fopen() is probably the best way to express what "existing file" means.  Well answered.
